# Define type from existed function

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I create the type from existed function in Dart/Flutter?

I know `typedef` can create custom type, something like:

```dart
typedef Custom<T> = int Function(T a, T b)
```

But if I have a function from the dependency and want to create the type for arguments, how can I do this?

```dart
int functionFromDependency(String a, {int b, ComplexType c}) {
  // ...
}

// something syntax like `typeof<functionFromDependency>`
void myProcess(typeof<functionFromDependency>? runner) {
  (runner ?? functionFromDependency)(
    a,
    b: b,
    c: c
  );
}
```

It is helpful for testing which can inject custom function.

Comment: You can't do it, and I don't think it makes sense anyway since your `myProcess` function already depends on the actual type of `runner` when passing arguments. `myProcess` needs to take a function with a specific signature, and callers need to conform to `myProcess`'s API, not the other way around.

Comment: Agree, just want to make sure if there has any syntactic sugar for this.

Answer (score 1):

Dart doesn't have something like C++'s `decltype` that would allow you to statically re-use the type of some other variable.

In the case of a callback argument to a function, I don't think that it would make sense anyway.  For example, you could give up static type-checking and do:

```dart
void myProcess(Function? runner) {
  (runner ?? functionFromDependency)(
    a,
    b: b,
    c: c
  );
}
```

but ultimately `myProcess` still requires that `runner` be a function that can takes a single positional argument and that can take named parameters `b` and `c`, all with types appropriate for the supplied arguments.  You might as well do:

```dart
typedef MyProcessCallback = void Function(A a, {B b, C, c});

void myProcess(MyProcessCallback? runner) {
  ...
}
```

`myProcess` should not be trying to conform to its callers; that's backwards.  Callers of `myProcess` should be conforming to `myProcess`'s API instead, which is much easier.